# Comparison amongst characters

Tags: java

Suppose I have a function which takes in two values and returns one value, as per the rule:

```
(x,y) should return y
(y,z) should return z 
(z,x) should return x

(y,x) should return y
(z,y) should return z 
(x,z) should return x
```

How to I store these cases? The ordering of the parameters do not matter. I do not want to use a series of nested if else statements

Comment: Does `(x,y)` have a mathematical meaning I am unaware of? Otherwise 'return the 2nd argument' seems to fulfill the spec.

Comment: See my answer - your question is very vague at the moment. My answer matches everything you've said you wanted, but it wouldn't be useful. Rather than *just* giving 3 examples, why don't you say what the *purpose* of the function is meant to be?

Comment: What is the purpose of this one, if you know the second parameter then you can use directly no need to implement anything for it.

Comment: Do you know what all of the possible parameters are?

Comment: What are x, y and z? What happens if you pass in a different value? At the moment, this answer is too vague to be answerable.

Comment: Yes, I know all the possible arguments !!

Comment: @CSSS.. If the ordering doesn't matter, then on what condition you return `y` from `x, y`?

Comment: @RohitJain: That's how I have to store the possible combinations and their solutions !!

Comment: @CSSS, May be your return values will change in case of (x,y) may be x or y on the basis of rules....right?

Comment: @CSSS. Then store it in some data structure, and fetch the corresponding value when you need it.

Comment: @RohitJain: This is what I am asking.. Which data structure should I use ?

Comment: @Anandkumar: Yeah .. something like that !!

Comment: @CSSS. From what you have shown till now, it seems like you need a `HashMap` and a `Custom class` to store the possible combination.

Comment: @RohitJain: How can I use a HashMap in here.. I have a 2 element key and also Their ordering doesn't matter !!

Comment: How many edits does this question need before it becomes remotely comprehensible?  I bet '42'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to code scissors, paper, stone.  For a long answer to your problem, look here:  http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Java.

Understanding the code in the `enum` section and the `while` loop in `run()` on that page should help you to distil the code into a method you can use

Comment: *"You are trying to code scissors, paper, stone."*  How did you figure that out?

Comment: y beats x. z beats y. x beats z.  Sound familiar?

Comment: How can I use enumerations here !! I think the arguments have a cyclic priority!!

Comment: *"Sound familiar?"*  Now you mention it.  Thanks for explaining, I might otherwise have accused you of practicing the black arts.  ;)

Comment: @csss didn't say _i've_ grokked it fully  ;-), but it involves an `enum` 'Item', and a `List<Item>` in combination.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson np. I just looked at the simple version of his question.  there are only x, y, and z.  everyone else was looking for a calculation to solve (I actually thought i was being facetious when i first commented on the question)